# Serilog global scope

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

Background:

- I'm using Serilog as a "backend" for `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`.
- I have a `class T` receiving `ILogger<T>` via DI.
- `T` performs various activities in several `async` methods (e.g. `M1Async`, `M2Async`) and logs heavily.
- There is a "global state" which is needed to be logged with every message emitted from `T`.
- Big part of this state is invariant, only few properties change from time to time.
- `T` shares Serilog configuration with other classes in the app, so it's a bit unpractical to have custom enricher which would be applied to `T` only.
- So I decided to use `logger.BeginScope()` to create the global state and every time it changes, I (dispose the old one and) recreate it.
- From the point of view of `T`'s methods, the state is global (just resides in private r/w member).

Let's have following scenario:

- Instance of `T` is created, `loggerScope` is built (as `logger.BeginScope()`).
- `M1Async` gets called, logs something (which emits the expected `loggerScope`'s content).
- `M1Async` detects state change and recreates the `loggerScope` with new content and exits.
- `M2Async` gets called, logs something (which emits the unexpected original `loggerScope`'s content, not the one the `M2Async` prepared).

The whole idea behind the global state was:

- Only few recreations of the `loggerScope`.
- Readable code.

Questions:

1. Is there any reason why the scopes are modified back such way?
2. Is there any way how to prevent it (configuration, attribute, hack, whatever else)?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Serilog sources](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Extensions.Logging/Extensions/Logging/SerilogLoggerProvider.cs), it looks like the `CurrentScope` is declared `AsyncLocal`, meaning the mentioned behavior is intended and there is no code which would potentially allow to avoid it.